# How could I parse specific JSON data in jQuery, without using $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a data from server like this

```
{"hello2": "world2", "hello3": ["world3", "second_world3"], "hello1": "world1"}
```

And I want console.log() to get only one value : `second_world3`

Is there any way except using `$.each`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var json  = {"hello2": "world2", "hello3": ["world3", "second_world3"], "hello1": "world1"}

alert(json.hello3[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is not really clear, does your object is always in the same format? You can use plain JavaScript for that:

```
var myObject = {"hello2": "world2", "hello3": ["world3", "second_world3"], "hello1": "world1"};
console.log(myObject.hello3[1]);
```